# how would the osmoregulatory and excretory systems would be for a flying human

Tags: science-based, creature-design, humanoid, avian

How would the excretory and osmoregulatory systems be for a flying human?

Comment: Why do you think it would be different / care to take a guess?

Comment: How? Gross, I'm afraid.

Comment: No context to suggest they wouldn't just ring up and order pizza and apart from the minor detail of getting the wings out of the way when you crap, there's no issue you tell us about - and you tell us nothing - to suggest any difference at all.

Comment: I can't see any particular reason for an osmoregulatory change, unless the body loses more water through sweating because of increased wind, which should be handled by changes in the skin's sweat glands or of the thermoregulatory systems. Excretory systems would only change if you assume a need to excrete while still in the air, in which case a reconfiguration of the excretory ports would be expected, which would also be a change in the gluteal structure. A combination of the urinary tract outflow with the bowel would seem likely.

Comment: Hi Iris, welcome to Worldbuilding! Interesting first question, but as some other commenters have pointed out this question needs some additional information about your flying humans as well as your expectations for them. Until you get a chance to add those details, I've voted to place your question [on hold](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se) so you aren't swamped with unhelpful answers. I'd also encourage you to check out our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)!

Comment: It's reasonable to expect flying humanoids would have excretory systems & osmoregulatory systems similar to those of birds. Flying humanoids would need similar adaptations for flight.

Comment: This question should be reopened as the specific expertise required to answer it is an understanding of avian biology. This means it isn't primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @a4android I agree - I closed it under “unclear what you’re asking” because I think it needs more details about the flying humans and what we should expect their physiological differences to be. It could use some fleshing out and context in general, too.